# using variables with chart on tooltip

Tags: c#, charts, tooltip

My chart's X axis is the date, Y axis is the sum of 4 variables. Variables a, b, c, and d are different between -100 and +100 at each point of graph.

I want to show the values of each of the 4 separate variables used in the calculations on the tooltip screen at each point of this graph. How can I do it?

When I use the code below, the values of a, b, c, and d on the last date on the chart are the same as the tooltips at all points of the graph. However, at each point, the variables take many different values.

```
chart1.Series["alarm"].Points.AddXY(tarih, a+b+c+d);

chart1.Series["alarm"].ToolTip = string.Format("#LEGENDTEXT\ra:{0}\rb:{1}\rc:{2}\rd:{3}",
                                               a.ToString(),
                                               b.ToString(),
                                               c.ToString(),
                                               d.ToString()
                                              );
```

Comment: Simply set the ToolTip of each DataPoint separately!

Comment: How? I used that code in each circle of adding data on chart but result is the same: all point's tooltip show me the same values.

Comment: You are adding a tooltip for each series. Replace `chart1.Series["alarm"].Points.AddXY` with `int index = chart1.Series["alarm"].Points.AddXY` and `chart1.Series["alarm"].ToolTip =`  with `chart1.Series["alarm"].Points[index].ToolTip =`

Comment: it works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ToolTips` not only at the `Series` level but also for each `DataPoint`.

Here is a simple change to your code:

```
int index = chart1.Series["alarm"].Points.AddXY(tarih, a+b+c+d);

chart1.Series["alarm"].Points[index].ToolTip = 
       string.Format("#LEGENDTEXT\ra:{0}\rb:{1}\rc:{2}\rd:{3}", a, b, c, d);
```